# Laravel Eloquent: Alphabetical Order but from Small words to Sentence

Tags: mysql, laravel, sorting, eloquent, sql-order-by

I have a dictionary in (English/Arabic) with more than 800,000 words in my MySQL Database. and i use Laravel Project for Managing that. in Search Bar create auto-complete but the problem in dictionary i have words & sentences. for example in this list (Json API) is `OrderBy ASC` in laravel Eloquent 5:

```
Acquaint with
Acquaintance
Acquire
Acquired
Acquisition
```

But i want Alphabetical Order but from `Words` to `Sentences` like that, Always mean the sentence comes down words:

```
Acquaintance
Acquire
Acquired
Acquisition
Acquaint with
```

This My Code:

```
      $result = AutoComplete::select('Translation')
                            ->where('Translation', 'LIKE', $search. '%')
                            ->limit(4)
                            ->distinct()
                            ->orderBy('Translation', 'asc')
                            ->get();
```

Please also alert me if the code is not optimized :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this can be done using two separate queries.

```
$words = AutoComplete::where('Translation', 'LIKE', "{$search}%")
    ->where('Translation', 'NOT LIKE', '% %')
    ->limit(5)
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('Translation')
    ->pluck('Translation');

$sentences = AutoComplete::where('Translation', 'LIKE', "{$search}%")
    ->where('Translation', 'LIKE', '% %')
    ->limit(5)
    ->distinct()
    ->orderBy('Translation')
    ->pluck('Translation');

$finalResults = $words->merge($sentences)->take(5);
```

You get from the DB up to 5 matching words, and up to 5 matching sentences.

Assuming you want to show only 5 total results, by combining these you get the top 5 matches ordered words before sentences.